# C# DateTime.UtcNow is returning the wrong value

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm having an issue that I'm having a hard time to figure out, which is the result of `DateTime.UtcNow`. In My local machine when I print it gives me the right time, but in my server it's 3 hours ahead. This is how I'm printing, in a Razor view:

```
<h1>@DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")</h1>
```

What can I check to make this give me the right time?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Your server's timezone is probably set wrong.

Comment: @AndréLuiz are you sure that time is the same on your server and on your localmachine ? Check the clock settings to see is time exactlly the same :)

Comment: looks like you server has time/timezone sync off. was there any hardware migrations from one region to another?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your server is set to the wrong time. Windows keeps the hardware clock set to local time so if the time is wrong in comparison to the timezone, that essentially means the system clock is not synchronized with UTC time.

If your timezone is set to Chicago timezone, the time on the system tray must also match Chicago time.

Comment: What time should set it to? To the timezone where it phisically is?

Comment: @AndréLuiz The most important thing is that it's time is set correctly for whatever timezone it's set to.  Typically you set servers to either the timezone where they exist or just set them to GMT.

Comment: @AndréLuiz Set timezone to UTC, set correct UTC time, set timezone to whatever you want.

Comment: @Joe Philips I've been trying to change the time zone one the server's clock but I don't notice any changes in the result. Would you know a way for me to check the windows hardware clock? IN my case my server is physically in the Netherlands

Comment: @AndréLuiz More importantly than changing the timezone, you have to actually adjust the time to MATCH the timezone...

Comment: @AndréLuiz Did you figure this out?

Comment: @JoePhillips I did. I actually didn't have to change the timezone, I had to sync with the internet time.